# A change in Swift1.2 that confused me

Tags: swift, uibutton

Before Swift 1.2, I wrote this code `Label.text = "Hi"` it's right, but after i updated Xcode to 6.3 with Swift 1.2, I got an error

> UIButton does not have a member named "text".

Seems like `text` is not a `String?` anymore.
How can i fix it?

Comment: Your label is a UIButton, not a UILabel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **not** do `myButton.text = ""`. That does not work and did not work before simply because a UIButton does not have an attribute called *text*.

What you can do to change the button's title is:

```
myButton.titleLabel.text = "button"
```

Hope that helps :)

**EDIT**

As I saw the pictures on your Twitter, this is the source of the error:

[image: Wrong declaration]

Even though you named the `IBOutlet` "QuestionLabel", it is an `UIButton`, instead of a label. Change that to `UILabel` to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, but actually, that's not 'myButton', it's a `Label` that i created on storyboard, in Swift 1.2, `String?` `"text"` does not exist anymore. Because I said it can be work on Swift 1.1

Comment: If you use a Label then the error shown does not fit. Make sure the problem is really about `myLabel.text`, not about a button.

Comment: It just don't have `text` anymore. I tried other projects, they all have that problem, no matter what's before the `.text`.

Comment: Ok, did you try `someLabel.text` or `someButton.text`?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your screen including declaration of the button / label and the error when trying to edit the `.text` property.

Comment: Thanks for assisting me, but I don't have enough rep, so I can't post pic. Yea I tried QuestionLabel, but still got that error.

Comment: You could upload it somewhere. Well, how did you create / declare the label?

Comment: I'll post it on my twitter my username is @AssenLixipu, you could see all my ViewController's content.

Answer (score 0):

UIButton does not have a member named "text" ever. Maybe you casted a UIButton to Label?

Comment: Thanks you for responding, and I just found that `text` is not a `String?` anymore, cause I can't found it on documents on Xcode.

Comment: @AssenRobin why should `text` not be a `String` anymore?!

Comment: If you have a latest Xcode 6.3 with Swift 1.2, you could find that when you type in `.text` after a label name or a tittle name, it just shows white color, it also won't pop out that optional choice window.

Comment: @HoaParis Thanks a lot, your answer helped me a little, but I have to accept the another one who through Twitter solved my problem. Sorry. But again, thank u !!